# jQuery: combining hashchange with a click function

Tags: jquery, html, css, hashchange

I'm having some trouble getting the hashchange function to work how I want it to. I currently have a masonry grid of divs, with a clearing div after every row (of 4), which is hidden. Clicking on one of the divs shows the closest clearing div, appends the relevant content inside it and reloads the masonry around it. 
This all works fine, but as I want to link to these divs that are being show from other pages I want to attach hashes to the functions. The hashes are being added to the URL, but if you load the URL it fails to run the function and show the relevant divs.
Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EV7yg/1/


jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).hashchange( function(){

    $(".content-block-footer").click(function () {

        $('.content-block-preview').hide();
        var previewForThis = $(this).parent(".content-block-small").nextAll('.content-preview:first');
        var otherPreviews = $(this).parent(".content-block-small").siblings('.content-preview').not(previewForThis);
        otherPreviews
            .addClass('excluded') // exclude other previews from masonry layout
            .hide();
        previewForThis
            .removeClass('excluded')
            .append($('#content-preview' + $(this).attr('hook')).show())
            .hide()
            .delay(400)
            .fadeIn("slow");
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top-95 }, 'slow');
        $('#block-wrap').masonry('reload');
    });
    });
$(window).hashchange();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="block-wrap">

<div class="content-block-small" style="background-color: white;">
<div class="content-block-footer" hook="01"><a href="#test01">READ MORE</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-block-small" style="background-color: white;">
<div class="content-block-footer" hook="02"><a href="#test02">READ MORE</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-block-small" style="background-color: white;">
<div class="content-block-footer" hook="03"><a href="#test03">READ MORE</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-block-small" style="background-color: white;">
<div class="content-block-footer" hook="04"><a href="#test04">READ MORE</a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="content-preview excluded">
</div>


<div id="content-preview01" class="content-block-preview">
CONTENT GOES HERE
</div>

<div id="content-preview02" class="content-block-preview">
CONTENT GOES HERE
</div>

<div id="content-preview03" class="content-block-preview">
CONTENT GOES HERE
</div>

<div id="content-preview04" class="content-block-preview">
CONTENT GOES HERE
</div>

</div>
```

Is it possible to attach hashes to such click functions and link to these hashes from exterior pages (showing the relevant content)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to put a click event handler into a hashchange event.

Have look at my forked fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y9X2D/35/

You can check the hash handling over the following url:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/y9X2D/35/show/

I just excluded the your click event code into a seperate function.
The click event now changes the url hash which fires the `hashchange` event.
the `hashchange` event then calls `showDetail`.

Of course you can also call `showDetail` directly without changing the hash.

```js
$(window).hashchange( function(){
    var hash = location.hash;
   if(hash)
   {
    var element = $('.content-block-footer[hook="'+hash.substring(1)+'"]');
     if(!element) element = $('.content-block-footer').first();
    showDetail(element);
   } else {
    element = $('.content-block-footer').first();
    showDetail(element);
   }
});

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(window).hashchange();

    $(".content-block-footer").click(function () {
        document.location.hash = $(this).attr('hook');
    });
});
```

Comment: ahh this looks to work perfectly in the jshell, but when I implement the code it reacts like the jsfiddle about and doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Can you point out what exactly doesn't work? The problem with the jsfiddle is just that it doesn't support url hashtags (I may be wrong with that but I wasn't able to do it so...)

Comment: Version 35 (updated the links) of the fiddle should actually work pretty well. I think the problem is that it crashed when there is no hash. You can see the change in the above code as well.

Comment: you beat me to it, yes that was the problem, I noticed when removing the hashes from the url it crashed the demo. This works great now, pretty much exactly what I was trying to achieve, thanks for that, much appreciated! There is one small thing, the first instance of `.content-preview` is being shown on page load, I don't want to show any when the page loads, only when you click on the relevant div etc. For some strange reason as well the page scroll to the bottom on page load as well which is a bit odd?

Comment: Just use `if(element) showDetail(element);` instead of `if(!element) element = $('.content-block-footer').first();
    showDetail(element);` And additionally remove the else statement.

Comment: And remove `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: element.offset().top-95 }, 'slow');` in `showDetail`. This should remove the animation.

Comment: actually, there was one small issue I've noticed now I've started adding content. As I've now taken out the scroll effect, it doesn't scroll to the bottom of the page when it loads, but is it not possible to scroll to the relevant div in the url. e.g. `www.example.com/#01` would scroll to `.content-preview-01` on the page load?